# Connecting to Oracle using UCP and DataDirect driver

Tags: ucp

I am trying to connect to a Oracle database using UCP with DataDirect JDBC driver for oracle.
What is the URL tha tI need to use. I am currently using the following.

```
<property name="URL" value="jdbc:datadirect:oracle:TNSNamesFile=C:\\Oracle\\11.2.0\\client_1_X64\\network\\admin\\tnsnames.ora;TNSServerName=TESTA"/>
```

I get the error 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][Oracle JDBC Driver]A host name must be specified if a port number is specified.

Why do I get this error?
Is it possible to use UCP with DataDirect JDBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your URL is correct, here is the sample URL from the documentation:

```
jdbc:datadirect:oracle:TNSNamesFile=c:\\oracle\\NETWORK\\ADMIN\\tnsnames.ora;
    TNSServerName=FITZGERALD.SALES
```

You can go here for more information on connecting to Oracle database using UCP with DataDirect JDBC :

http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/jdbc/alljdbc/userguide/jdbcoracle.11.08.html#974893

One thing you might try is using a hostname and port number, here's a sample URL:

```
jdbc:datadirect:oracle://server3:1521;ServiceName=ORCL;User=test;
Password=secret
```